# Hadoop Reduce side what is really occurred?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I'm reading "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" and I have some questions.

In Chapter 7 "How MapReduce Works" on page 201, the author said that in reduce side

> When **[A]** the in-memory buffer reaches a threshold size (controlled by `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent`) or **[B]** reaches a threshold number of map outputs (`mapreduce.reduce.merge.inmem.threshold`), it is merged and spilled to disk.

My questions (4 questions) are about conditions **A** and **B**.

In condition **A** with default values config Hadoop 2 would you say that

1. Will 0.462(0.66 * 0.70) of 1GB memory reducer is full (462MB), will merge and spill is begin?

In condition **B** with default values config would you say that

2. When 1000 pairs of key-value map output from one mapper have been collected in buffer, will merge and spill is begin?
3. in above question one mapper is correct or more than one mapper from different machine?

in following paragraph, The author said that

> As the copies accumulate on disk, a background thread merges them into larger, sorted files

4. it is correct that your intended purpose is that when a spill file wants to write to disk a before spill that already exist in disk merge with current spill?

Please help me to better understand what is really happening in Hadoop.

---

Please see this image
 
Each mapper run in different machine 
Anyone can explain precise meaning as specified  [image]

Answer (score 1):

1. **Will 0.462(0.66 * 0.70) of 1GB memory reducer is full (462MB), will merge and spill is begin?**
   Yes. This will trigger the merge and spill to disk.
   By default each reducer get 1GB of heap space, of this only 70% `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent` is to be used as merge and shuffle buffer, the 30% might be needed by reducer code, and for other task specific requirements. When 66% `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent` of the merge and shuffle buffer is full merging (and spill) is triggred, to make sure some space if left for process to sorting and during the sort the other incoming files are not waiting for memory space.
   refer http://www.bigsynapse.com/mapreduce-internals

2. **When 1000 pairs of key-value map output from one mapper have been collected in buffer, will merge and spill is begin?**
   No. Here *map outputs* may refer to the partitions of map output file. (I think). 
   1000 key value pair might be a very small amount of memory.
   In slide 24 of this [presentation by cloudera](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/mr-perf/24-Reducer_merge_triggers_RAMManager_Total) the same is refered as *segments*

   > `mapreduce.reduce.merge.inmem.threshold` segments accumulated (default 1000)

3. **in above question one mapper is correct or more than one mapper from different machine?**
   From my understanding, 1000 partitions can come from different partitions. As the partitions of map output files are bieng copied parallely from different nodes.

4. **it is correct that your intended purpose is that when a spill file wants to write to disk a before spill that already exist in disk merge with current spill?**
   No, a (mapper output) partition file currently in memory is merged with other (mapper output) partition files in memory only to create a spill file and written to disk. This might be repeated several times as the buffer fills up. Thus many files would have been written to disk. To increase efficiency these files in disk are merged into a larger file by a background process.

source:
Hadoop the definitive guide. 4th edition.
http://answers.mapr.com/questions/3952/reduce-merge-performance-issues.html
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml
http://www.bigsynapse.com/mapreduce-internals
http://answers.mapr.com/questions/3952/reduce-merge-performance-issues.html

Comment: Thanks for your attention in question 4 according to sentences "Each time the memory buffer reaches the spill threshold, a new spill file is created, so after the map task has written its last output record, there could be several spill files." page 200 "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" when a previous spill write to disk new spill is created therefore it is not possible 2 spill simultaneously exist in RAM. and merging occur on them

Comment: @aminir Yes you are right. I meant to say "(mapper output) partition file" instead of "spill file". My bad, I have fixed it.

Comment: @aminir Could you also share the source where that image came from. It might clear some of my doubts as well.

Comment: I've created this image.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to @shanmuga's answer.

1) Note that **NOT** all map outputs are stored in memory first and then spilled to disk.
Some map outputs are directly stored on Disk (*OnDiskMapOutput*). 
Based on the uncompressed map output length (*Size*) it is determined if this particular Map's output will be saved in Memory or on Disk. The decision is based on:

```
Map Output Buffer Limit (MemoryLimit) = mapreduce.reduce.memory.totalbytes [Default = -Xmx * mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent [Default = 70%]]

MaxSingleShuffleLimit = MemoryLimit * mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent [Default = 25%]
```

- If *Size* > *MaxSingleShuffleLimit* => **OnDiskMapOutput**
- Else If
  (Total size of current Map Outputs Buffer Used) < *MemoryLimit* =>
  ***InMemoryMapOutput***
- Else => Halt the process

2) The SORT/MERGE phase is triggered during the COPY phase when either of these conditions are met:

- At the end of an *InMemoryMapOutput* creation, if

  (total size of
     current set of *InMemoryMapOutput*) > MemoryLimit *
     mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent [Default: 90%]
  , start the
  *InMemoryMerger* thread which merges all the current *InMemoryMapOutputs* to one *OnDiskMapOutput*.
- At the end of an *OnDiskMapOutput* creation, if

  (No. of OnDiskMapOutputs) > 2 * mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor [Default 64
     (CDH)/100(Code)]

, start the *OnDiskMerger* thread which merges *mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor* OnDiskOutputs to one OnDiskOutput.

3) Regarding Condition B you mentioned, I don't see the flag *mapreduce.reduce.merge.inmem.threshold* referenced in the Merge related source code for MapReduce. This flag is ***perhaps*** deprecated.